# perl $|=1; What is this?

Tags: perl

I am learning Writing CGI Application with Perl -- Kevin Meltzer . Brent Michalski

Scripts in the book mostly begin with this:

```
#!"c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -wT
# sales.cgi
$|=1;
use strict;
use lib qw(.);
```

What's the line $|=1; How to space it, eg. $| = 1; or $ |= 1; ?
Why put use strict; after $|=1; ?

Thanks

Comment: Writing CGI Application with Perl is a good book, but very, very (10 years!) old. The best practices and the language ecosystem have evolved a lot in that time, make sure you also read some recent material, search for "modern perl", or "learning perl"

Comment: @mirod Just to provide the missing linkt to [modern perl on github](https://github.com/chromatic/modern_perl_book) as it is stil active and gets updated from time to time.

Comment: @mirod now you made me nostalgic.. 1995, I used `Netscape for the Macintosh`, and it could fit on a 1,44mb floppy disc. ;)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) is your friend. It documents all these cryptic special variables.

**$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH (aka $|):**

> > **If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or print on the currently selected output channel.** Default is 0 (regardless of whether the channel is really buffered by the system or not; $| tells you only whether you've asked Perl explicitly to flush after each write). STDOUT will typically be line buffered if output is to the terminal and block buffered otherwise. *Setting this variable is useful primarily when you are outputting to a pipe or socket*, such as when you are running a Perl program under rsh and want to see the output as it's happening. *This has no effect on input buffering.* See getc for that. See select on how to select the output channel. See also IO::Handle.
> >
> > Mnemonic: when you want your pipes to be piping hot.

Happy coding.

---

For the other questions:

There is no reason that `use strict;` comes after `$|`, except by the programmers convention. `$|` and other special variables are not affected by strict in this way. The spacing is also not important -- just pick your convention and be consistent. (I prefer spaces.)

Answer (score 21):

`$| = 1;` forces a flush after every write or print, so the output appears as soon as it's generated rather than being buffered.

See the [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) documentation.

`$|` is the name of a special variable.  You shouldn't introduce a space between the `$` and the `|`.

Whether you use whitespace around the `=` or not doesn't matter to Perl.  Personally I think using spaces makes the code more readable.

Why the `use strict;` comes after `$| = 1;` in your script I don't know, except that they're *both* the sort of thing you'd put right at the top, and you have to put them in one order or the other.  I don't think it matters which comes first.

Comment: For "auto-flush", is there some other (more readable) command alternative to the `$| = 1;` trick?

Comment: Yes - search for `$|` in the documentation that I link to in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

It does not matter where in your script you put a `use` statement, because they all get evaluated at compile time.

`$|` is the built-in variable for autoflush. I agree that in this case, it is ambiguous. However, a lone `$` is not a valid statement in perl, so by process of elimination, we can say what it must mean.

`use lib qw(.)` seems like a silly thing to do, since "." is already in `@INC` by default. Perhaps it is due to the book being old. This statement tells perl to add "." to the `@INC` array, which is the "path environment" for perl, i.e. where it looks for modules and such.

Comment: **It does not matter where in your script you put a use statement**: Not completely true:  `use strict` is one of many *lexical* pragmas.  If you have `blah blah { use strict; blarg blarg } blah blah` in your script, only the "blarg blarg" will be covered by the strict pragma.

Comment: in taint mode removes the current working directory from @INC, so need to add it back to the module by use lib qw(.)