# Write to standard output

Tags: perl

I have a perl process which run every day automaticaly, it takes about 20 minutes and finnish and print every opertion to stdout worht to mention every operation takes about second .

Sometimes it seems that the stdout is stucked and i need to  click enter in order for the process to continue running .

could someone experience such issue/and suggestion how to handle this issue ?

below a snapshot of my code:

```
foreach (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (validate($_) == 0) {
        print "$_ validated with Success\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$_ validated with failure\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't help without seeing the code; preferably the minimum amount needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: In which operation system? Linux (or nevertheless Windows)? Maybe flushing is needed (buffered output). Or the terminal window was blocked.

Comment: in windows operating system

Comment: Post your perl program or noone will be able to help you. Before posting, strip your program down to the neccesary parts, or probably noone will be willing to help you.

Comment: Posted the neccesary  part

Comment: How big is the input?  The `foreach(<>)` construct will read the entire file into memory before starting.  You may to use the `while(<>)` construct.

Comment: The input is about 1 GB

Answer (score 1):

As Bill Ruppert writes, you need to use `while (<>)` instead of `foreach (<>)` in order to allow the `print` statements to be executed after each line of input is read.

As Joop Eggen writes, you need to make sure your standard output is not written in blocks in order to make sure that each line of output appears immediately after a `print` statement has been issued. This can be done by setting the [`$|`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303515/perl-1-what-is-this) variable.